# AngularJS setting default value for ng-hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im having a issue with hiding elements. Basically i want to set defaults for what elements are hidden/shown when the page is loaded.

Im hiding my elements via the ng-hide that is bound to a model that is set from the controller, and ng-repeated over in the view.

The checkbox is bound correctly, but the content in not hidden by default, you will have to click the checkbox twice for it to correctly hide the element.

Demo is found here: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SBoysvAeCFSnv36oVKyj)

Comment: when it is "checked" you want to hide a relevant column or to show it?

Comment: I was thinking of hiding the columns when the checkbox is checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works when these models are defined. You can use `ng-init` for this purpose:

```
 ng-init="$parent[col.model]=col.checked"
```

Working plnk: http://plnkr.co/edit/pUAufB?p=preview

Comment: @PatrikStorm this way (Q&A) is my best way for learning stuff !

Answer (score 1):

The first time odd behaviour is due to you mobile property `checkedContainer` has not been created till the binding is evaluate based on your interaction with the checkboxes.

In the controller if you do

`$scope.checkedContainer=true;` your code would work.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I got it figured out. As i could have guessed, a scoping issue..